# Reference background-image in CSS - application MVC 3 ASP.NET in IIS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I have an application hosted in IIS

[image]

But not working the *background-image* from CSS file

The css is referenced from the layout with:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/NewStyleSUPERADMIN/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the *style.css*, I have:

```
background-image: url('/content/themes/NewStyleMeduimHarder/images/Bottom_texture.jpg');
```

or

```
background-image: url('/content/themes/NewStyleMeduimHarder/images/Bottom_texture.jpg');
```

How do I display the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a relative path. [Partial `urls` are resolved relative to the style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url):

```
background-image: url(images/Bottom_texture.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the css you should only use `url(../images/Bottom_texture.jpg)`

And as far as I can see you should also change the url to the css to `@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/NewStyleSUPERADMIN/style.css")`

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. I put the images in a folder called "Images." Then I put in this: `url("../Images/nameofpicture.gif")`

Answer (score 0):

The url should be

```
url(themes/NewStyleMeduimHarder/images/Bottom_texture.jpg)
```

With respect to the Content folder.